# Java application (Minecraft) can't be launched from desktop

Tags: java, .desktop, minecraft

I'm okay with the terminal, but I'm trying to learn how to use the gnome gui. 
The following command works no problem in the terminal:
/usr/bin/java -Xms2048M -Xmx4096M -jar /home/luke/.minecraft/PixelMonServer/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2768-universal.jar nogui

I have created a .desktop file for it and placed it in '~/Desktop' and '~/.local/share/applications'. It looks good in both places (icon displays, I can find it in Activities) but it doesn't seem to actually do anything. Nothing fires up, and 'ps -ef | grep java' shows no running java processes.

The contents of my .desktop file are below:

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Pixelmon Server
Comment=Start Pixelmon Server
Exec=/usr/bin/java -Xms2048M -Xmx4096M -jar /home/luke/.minecraft/PixelMonServer/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2768-universal.jar nogui
Icon=/home/luke/Pictures/pixelmon.png
Terminal=True
Type=Application
Categories=Game;

edit: I figured this out. If anyone else has a similar problem, check below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. In case anyone else has a similar problem: I believe the reason it was not working is because the Minecraft server was looking for eula.txt in my current working directory.

I made a bash script which started with 'cd my_path' and then pointed the desktop shortcut to that. It now works.