# Ubuntu not starting Java GUI application except from terminal

Tags: .desktop, javafx

I've recently migrated from latest Mint to Ubuntu 23.10 (x64).

In Mint, I used to start a JavaFX GUI app using desktop launcher (java -jar ... defined in ~/.local/share/applications) and it worked fine.

In Ubuntu, the desktop launcher doesn't do anything and Alt-F2 doesn't start it either.
The only way to start it is opening a terminal and starting the command from the terminal window. What could be the problem?

Note: There isn't a working directory issue like in the question [Java application (Minecraft) can't be launched from desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166045/java-application-minecraft-cant-be-launched-from-desktop).

Answer (score 0):

Having `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-18/bin/"` just in my `.bashrc`, only terminal knew `java` command.

(`/var/log/syslog` was containing items with unknown command `java`)